# Можно ли в VS Code отдать предпочтение нажатия интегрированной консоли?

Tags: visual-studio-code

В некоторых пакетах linux (например: htop, mc) зарегистрированы кнопки F1-F12 для управления. Если нажать на зарегистрированную в VS Code клавишу (например F1 - команды, или F5 - дебагер), то сработает команда в VS Code, а консольная не сработает. Можно ли изменить это и при активной консоли учитывать нажатия клавиш для нее?

Comment: Вообще довольно странная идея запускать htop и mc внутри консоли vscode

Comment: @insolor почему? Открывать отдельный mRemoteNG какой-нибудь только ради этого - не странная идея? Когда VS Code позволяет заниматься удаленной разработкой...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается из коробки действительно есть такая возможность.

```
"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
    "-workbench.action.showCommands",
    "-workbench.action.terminal.findNext",
    "-workbench.action.debug.start",
    "-workbench.action.toggleFullScreen",
],
```